# C++ Avro: how to initialize ValidSchema with auto generated schema?

Tags: c++, avro

I have an auto generated avro schema which I can encode and decode to avro memory streams.

Now, I would like to write to a file, and I have to some how activate my file writer with the following:

```
#include "avro/Encoder.hh"
#include "avro/Decoder.hh"
#include "avro/ValidSchema.hh"
#include "avro/Compiler.hh"
#include "avro/DataFile.hh

avro::ValidSchema loadSchema(const char* filename)
{
     std::ifstream ifs(filename);
     avro::ValidSchema result;
     avro::compileJsonSchema(ifs, result);
     return result;
}

int
main()
{
     avro::ValidSchema cpxSchema = loadSchema("cpx.json");

     {
         avro::DataFileWriter<c::cpx> dfw("test.bin", cpxSchema);
         c::cpx c1;
         for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
             c1.re = i * 100;
             c1.im = i + 100;
             dfw.write(c1);
         }
         dfw.close();
     }

     {
         avro::DataFileReader<c::cpx> dfr("test.bin", cpxSchema);
         c::cpx c2;
         while (dfr.read(c2)) {
             std::cout << '(' << c2.re << ", " << c2.im << ')' << std::endl;
         }
     }
     return 0;

}
```

So, I have my auto-generated file in `auto_generated.hh` (command: `avrogencpp -i schema.json -o auto_generated.hh -n auto_generated`) and I have included all relevant files therein, and short of loading the schema from my json file (which seems to be beside the point if I have already auto-generated everything), I have tried the following:

```
#include "auto_generated.hh"

int main(){

    /* 
        auto_generated::schema() is going to produce the datum which I am
        storing. 

        auto_generated::schema is the struct which contains the data
        members which will be set during the course of data output.

    */ 


    //avro::ValidSchema vs; vs.setSchema(auto_generated::schema);

    // auto_generated::schema schema = auto_generated::schema();
    // avro::ValidSchema vs(schema);

    // avro::ValidSchema vs;
    // auto_generated::schema schema = auto_generated::schema();
    // vs.setSchema(schema);

    avro::ValidSchema vs;
    avro::Schema s = auto_generated::schema(); // or without ()
    vs.setSchema(s);

    // etc.

    avro::DataFileWriter<auto_generated::schema> dfw("foo",vs);
}
```

How do I initialize the `ValidSchema` and construct the `DataFileWriter` so as to write my data to a file?